# How can I have code called (e.g., a function) when the player changes text cursor position in a multiline text box?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'd like to use something like a [multiline editable box](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Components/UMultiLineEditableTextBox/index.html) widget for my UMG ui, and have something happen when the text cursor moves, in any of the various ways that can occur. How can I get my code called at these times, and also how do I get information about where the cursor currently is in the text?

I see in the `SMultiLineEditableTextBox` slate class there is an [`OnCursorMoved`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Slate/Widgets/Text/SMultiLineEditableText/OnCursorMoved/index.html) function, which has a an [`FTextLocation&`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Slate/Framework/Text/FTextLocation/index.html) parameter. However, no UMG widget seems to expose that functionality, so it's unclear how I could make a UMG widget use that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a child class of `UMultiLineEditableTextBox`, which has a function with the same signature as `OnCursorMoved`. This class will also need to override `TSharedRef<SWidget> RebuildWidget()`:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/MultiLineEditableTextBox.h"
#include "MyEditable.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class UMyEditable : public UMultiLineEditableTextBox
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    virtual TSharedRef<SWidget> RebuildWidget() override;

protected:
    virtual void HandleOnCursorMoved(const FTextLocation& InLocation);
};
```

In the override, do the same thing that `UMultiLineEditableTextBox`does *and also* set the `OnCursorMoved` delegate to the function declared above. Use `BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(SMultiLineEditableText::FOnCursorMoved, [your function name])`.  Then, also define your function and use the passed in `FTextLocation` as desired:

```
#include "MyEditable.h"
#include "Widgets/SWidget.h"
#include "Widgets/Input/SMultiLineEditableTextBox.h"

TSharedRef<SWidget> UMyEditable::RebuildWidget()
{
    MyEditableTextBlock = SNew(SMultiLineEditableTextBox)
        .Style(&WidgetStyle)
        .TextStyle(&TextStyle)
        .AllowContextMenu(AllowContextMenu)
        .IsReadOnly(bIsReadOnly)
        //      .MinDesiredWidth(MinimumDesiredWidth)
        //      .Padding(Padding)
        //      .IsCaretMovedWhenGainFocus(IsCaretMovedWhenGainFocus)
        //      .SelectAllTextWhenFocused(SelectAllTextWhenFocused)
        //      .RevertTextOnEscape(RevertTextOnEscape)
        //      .ClearKeyboardFocusOnCommit(ClearKeyboardFocusOnCommit)
        //      .SelectAllTextOnCommit(SelectAllTextOnCommit)
        .VirtualKeyboardOptions(VirtualKeyboardOptions)
        .VirtualKeyboardDismissAction(VirtualKeyboardDismissAction)
        .OnTextChanged(BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(FOnTextChanged, HandleOnTextChanged))
        .OnTextCommitted(BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(FOnTextCommitted, HandleOnTextCommitted))
        .OnCursorMoved(BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(SMultiLineEditableText::FOnCursorMoved, HandleOnCursorMoved))
        ;

    return MyEditableTextBlock.ToSharedRef();
}

void UMyEditable::HandleOnCursorMoved(const FTextLocation& InLocation)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Cursor Moved!"));
}
```